# ApexCharts impossible to set the logarithmic option in javascript

Tags: bar-chart, logarithm, apexcharts, yaxis

I use a DrawChart method and try to set the **logarithmic** option to the **yaxis** to **true** without success:

The datas (for the series) contains :

"[{type:"bar",data:[1.19576304413727E-08,1.30322021618667E-07]}]"

I try to place the logarithmic : true option in several place without succes. For me it must be placed into the yaxis part.

Thank you in advance

```
chart.updateOptions({
                        series: datas,
                        chart: {
                            toolbar: {
                                show: showToolbar
                            },
                            animations: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            type: 'bar'                      
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            bar: {
                                horizontal: false,
                                columnWidth: '50%',
                                endingShape: 'rounded'
                            }         
                        },
                        stroke: {
                            show: true,
                            width: 2,
                            colors: ['transparent']
                        },
                        xaxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Masse'
                            },
                            categories: categories//,
                            //tickAmount: 10
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function (value) {
                                    //var ex;
                                    return value.toExponential();
                                    //return value;
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: unit
                            },
                            tickAmount: 10
                            
                            //min: min,
                            //max: max,
                            //decimalsInFloat: 3
                        },
                        grid: {
                            padding: {
                                left: 50,
                                right: 50
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'bottom',
                            horizontalAlign: 'left',
                            showForSingleSeries: true,
                            showForNullSeries: true,
                            showForZeroSeries: true
                        },
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !

When you have log values really small (like  5.32E-9), the logarithm option doesnt work if you try to display the legend thrue a JS function.

So multiply by 1E10 the divide into the JS function (where you display the legend) by 1E10.